# AWS ElasticBeanstalk unable to read appsettings using ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in ASP.NET Core web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

### Background & Attempted Fixes

I am attempting to automate my .NET Core web application deployment using AWS ElasticBeanstalk and configuring each environment with the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable.

I then found out that via numerous ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855453/access-aws-elasticbeanstalk-custom-environment-variables-with-net-core-webapp) & [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127703/aws-elastic-beanstalk-environment-in-asp-net-core-1-0)) Stackoverflow questions this is broken in ElasticBeanstalk.

Then following those two SO questions, I tried this in my `Startup.cs`:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddJsonFile(@"C:\Program Files\Amazon\ElasticBeanstalk\config\containerconfiguration", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = builder.Build();

    var ebConfig = ParseEbConfig(Configuration);
    builder.AddInMemoryCollection(ebConfig);

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()                
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
        .CreateLogger();

    CurrentEnvironment = env;
}

public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }
public IHostingEnvironment CurrentEnvironment { get; set; }

private static Dictionary<string, string> ParseEbConfig(IConfiguration config)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (IConfigurationSection pair in config.GetSection("iis:env").GetChildren())
    {
        string[] keypair = pair.Value.Split(new[] { '=' }, 2);
        dict.Add(keypair[0], keypair[1]);
    }

    return dict;
}
```

and tried accessing the new `containerconfiguration` values in my `HomeController` (to test this out) like this: `_config.GetSection("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT").Value;` where `_config` is `IConfiguration`. **This worked when debugging locally** & I was able to get the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` properly. But in Beanstalk it was unable to find that variable.

### What seems to be going on

So it appears that Beanstalk is unable to access the `containerconfiguration` file and it certainly is not able to retrieve the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable, no matter where I set it in my configurations with Beanstalk.

### What I am wondering

At the end of the day, I want to be able to set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable to `Dev` (for example) in my Beanstalk configuration and have my .NET application load the appropriate `appsettings.json` file for the environment. I don't necessary need to go the route of the `containerconfiguration` file, but this seems to be the way it needs to be done.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47648283/60576 for a solution that actually works for every scenario (also for ASP.NET Core 2).